# Trouble getting sshuttle to start up with --DNS routing

Tags: python, macos, ssh, dns, tunnel

I've successfully run tunnels to this same machine, but I can't get sshuttle to load up with --dns.  Without it, it loads and works.  Here is the command line and console returns... any ideas?

No matter what I do, I just can't get this bad boy to fire up with the --dns enabled.

```
$ sshuttle --dns -vr server:8080 0/0
Starting sshuttle proxy.
Listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
DNS listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
firewall manager ready.
c : connecting to server...
Password:
 s: latency control setting = True
 s: available routes:
 s:   10.0.0.0/8
 s:   10.0.0.1/32
 s:   10.0.0.3/32
 s:   10.0.0.255/32
 s:   169.254.0.0/16
c : connected.
Connected.
firewall manager: starting transproxy.
>> ipfw -q add 12300 check-state ip from any to any
>> ipfw -q add 12300 skipto 12301 tcp from any to 127.0.0.0/8
>> ipfw -q add 12300 fwd 127.0.0.1,12300 tcp from any to 0.0.0.0/0 not ipttl 42 keep-state setup
>> ipfw -q add 12300 divert 12300 udp from any to 10.12.4.220/32 53 not ipttl 42
>> ipfw -q add 12300 divert 12300 udp from any to 10.1.8.128/32 53 not ipttl 42
>> ipfw -q add 12300 divert 12300 udp from any to 10.1.8.129/32 53 not ipttl 42
>> ipfw -q add 12300 divert 12300 udp from any 12300 to any not ipttl 42
c : DNS request from ('10.12.64.218', 51288): 23 bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "assembler.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "server.py", line 244, in main
  File "ssnet.py", line 555, in runonce
  File "ssnet.py", line 457, in callback
  File "ssnet.py", line 445, in handle
  File "ssnet.py", line 384, in got_packet
  File "server.py", line 232, in dns_req
  File "server.py", line 128, in __init__
  File "server.py", line 135, in try_send
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
firewall manager: undoing changes.
>> ipfw -q delete 12300
c : fatal: server died with error code 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you running on, and exactly which sshuttle version are you using?  This backtrace doesn't really make sense, as the error suggests a DNS lookup, while that part of the code isn't trying to do any DNS activity.  Have you modified your python install in any way?

Comment: Hi Apenwarr!  Thanks for the response.  I installed this with homebrew, so I'm assuming it's the latest?   Mac OSX 10.9.1.  The only thing I can think of is I had tried using "DNSCrypt" from OpenDNS.  Didn't really work for me because of blocked outbound ports.  So, I ran their uninstall script from Github, then removed logs with Hazel.  Do you think this may have something to do with it?  Any method of reverting to a "default" python install to verify?

Comment: FYI - just totally reinstalled OSX from recovery drive.  Same exact error.  Any ideas?

Comment: I had a very smilar problem with sshuttle crashing with the first dns lookup and finally nailed it down to the resolv.conf. In server.py[127], a random dns server is picked to forward the dns lookup to. In my case, my resolv.conf had 3 ipv4 and 3 ipv6 entries. After commenting out the ipv6 entries, sshuttle works perfectly with --dns. The code does not check if and what type of dns server is randomly picked, and so crashes if no or an invalid dns server is tried.

Comment: Floyd - Any idea what to do here?  I think this was modified by some other dns software I had tried to iunstall.  I have just this in my resolv.conf in /etc... what should they be, and where did yours come from?   1st line:  domain home    ;   second line:   nameserver 192.168.1.1

Comment: Upong further review - it appears that 192.168.1.1 is correctly deployed for resolvconf, a program that handles the need of multiple programs accessing resolv.conf.  That said, how can I edit or evaluate resolveconf files to fix this probelm with sshuttle, or what DNS should I use to tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error had to do with the dnsserver in resolv.conf, per my comments above.  I am not sure if changing it to a custom DNS server like google or safeDNS is a bad thing, but I did it, and it's working now as intended.  It seems there is an issue with routing in the resolvconf program, discovered here, where a guy did a similar thing to me to resolve, but a commenter indicated a deeper issue without detail on how to resolve:  http://opensourcemissions.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/sshuttle-dns-stopped-working-and-how-i-fixed-it/

Comment: I had a similar problem where the DNS entries in `resolve.conf` had commas at the end and confused sshuttle.